# Committing specific files of inner unmanaged repository from an outer managed repository

Tags: git, gitignore

From `~/` home directory in Linux, I would like to create a repository of useful files that I have customized over time. Specifically, for example, files like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.vimrc`.

Now, the home directory also has a `.vim` folder within which there are multiple plugins I have cloned. For e.g., `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets`. There is also the `.git/` folder within this folder at `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/.git`. These are repositories I cloned merely to use as a user. They are developed and maintained by someone else.

The presence of this latter `.git/` folder seems to prevent being able to track anything within the `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` folder or its subfolders from the repository I would like to create in `~/`. Some of the files within `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` that I have customized and changed include `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/tex.snippets` ,for instance, which contains my customization for LaTeX files. I would like to put this file under my personal source control repository under `~/`.

Regardless of having `!/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` in `~/.gitignore` the `tex.snippets` file is not tracked. However, everything else being the same, removing the `.git` folder from `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets` does track the `tex.snippets` file.

Is there anyway this problem can be resolved? I looked at submodules, but note that I do not want to commit to my repository under `~/` everything under `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` which seems to be the problem addressed by submodules. I only customize one or two files within `~/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` that I would like to commit to my personal source control repository under `~/`. Is deleting the `.git/` folder from `/.vim/plugged/vim-snippets/` the only way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *Git* way to do quite what you want—or at least, what I think you want, which is a kind of overlay/interleave thing.

I have, for my own personal use, my own personal dot-files system, and I would have the same issue if I customized directly-cloned repositories.  For now, if I did that, I'd go ahead and use submodules (or add something much like them to my personal dot-files system).  So far I have been fortunate in that the additional vim goodies I use are already sufficiently customizable without touching the original repository, that I don't have to do that.  So I have not actually implemented either of the tricks you're talking about.

What's really needed here, though, is a way to say "use a tree from some Git repository's commit, but use only these parts of it and/or overlay these other items into it".  This doesn't fit with the Git model so the *clone*, if any, of the other Git repository should go outside the assembled tree-of-files, and the tree-of-files should be able to live outside the Git repository.

Comment: Is there any harm in simply deleting the .git folder from the cloned repository locally? -- as a user of that repository and not a contributor. This gets the job done and seems quite clean for a user, in my view.

Comment: No, *except* that you're then responsible for maintaining the entire sub-repository, with no direct ability to update from "upstream" updates to that vim package. (You can of course manually merge.)

Comment: If the "upstream" developer changes something on his repository, could I not just uninstall that plugin/package -- which completely cleans up that folder in `~/.vim/plugged/` and then reinstall it which repopulates that folder including the new `.git/` folder (which I should then have to delete again, ad infinitum)?

Comment: Yes, that's the "manually merge" method. I've done that in the past, it gets old fast.